# can anyone help me improve this code in tb getting value through javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to get values of table from javascript. The code is working fine however i was wondering if it could be improved somehow and make sure it works on almost all of the modern browsers. The table list is changed more often and list is about 100 names long so that's why im asking for help. i would like to say thank you in advance for helping.Below is sample of my code and here is http://jsfiddle.net/g2s1ahcy/

HTML

```
<tr>
<td><a  href="/">left</a></td>
<td><a  id="toppart" href="/">Name</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a  href="/">left</a></td>
<td><a  id="label1" href="/">Name</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a  href="/">left</a></td>
<td><a  id="label2" href="/">Name</a></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("toppart").textContent="desc";
document.getElementById("label1").textContent="apple";
document.getElementById("label2").textContent="orange";
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the `textContent` of each element by id is different, how to make the code beautiful? So what's your question is?

Comment: yes it is different yes question might be how to make it more beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

1) I would use **`innerText`** or **`innerHTML`** instead of `textContent`

2) Maybe you could use **`querySelector`** instead of `getElementById`

HTML

```
<table class="data">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/">left</a></td>
        <td><a class="label1" href="/">Name</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/">left</a></td>
        <td><a class="label2" href="/">Name</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/">left</a></td>
        <td><a class="label3" href="/">Name</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('table > .label1').innerText = "apple";
document.querySelector('table > .label2').innerText = "oranges";
document.querySelector('table > .label3').innerText = "bananas";
```

**Note** that you can use the `id` attribute alright, but in long documents, id tags may become hard to maintain unique, giving you additional trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think the multiple lines of code can be simplified via using a map which maps each id-text_context pair.

Replcae code:

```
document.getElementById("toppart").textContent="desc";
document.getElementById("label1").textContent="apple";
document.getElementById("label2").textContent="orange";
```

With:

```
var id2Content = {
  "toppart": "desc",
  "label1": "apple",
  "label2": "orange"
};
for(var key in id2Content) {
  document.getElementById(key).textContent = id2Content[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

innerText doesn't work in firefox, so it's better to use innerHTML or textContent. You should take in account that innerHTML parses HTML code, like `<div id ="x">` or `<a href="">`... which is great but also takes resources (if you don't need that funtionality, better use textContent instead).

Also, in processing terms, `document.querySelector('#id1')` is equivalent to `document.getElementById(id1)`, but most advanced jQuery selectors overload the system, so you I'll recommend to use id selectors whenever you can.